# How to terminate the currently running async await thread manually in UWP?

Tags: async-await, uwp, dispose

How to terminate the currently running await thread manually in UWP. while disposing, facing problem in using async methods in my UWP app. After dispose method is called, await method keeps running and leads to crash.

Is there any possibility to kill the await thread manually in UWP?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does the API allow paying a cancellation token?

Comment: Please provide the code example what are you need to cancel

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, i can send you the sample if i was able to reproduce in a simple sample. But i can't reproduce it in a simple sample. My problem is "i used a code to open a stream in an await method it takes some time" when i try to close the app or switch the app at that time, dispose method was called and get Disposed" but the await thread still runs in a background process, while accessing disposed instances, it leads to crash.

Comment: Use cancellation token. And post the code where you calling async method